# How to allow all users to execute search API call for group members info

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, search-api

I'm having an issue with SharePoint 2013, In js file deployed on search page I need to check the users group by this API

```
/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('X')/Users
```

The problem is that the users don't have permission to make this api call, is there any solution to allow all users to perform this specific call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `View membership` of the group to `Everyone`.

Go to your SharePoint group > Group settings and then set `Who can view the membership of the group?` to Everyone and save the settings.

[image]